# Can I Use TypeScript instead of JavaScript for Minecraft Bedrock Edition modding?

Tags: javascript, typescript, minecraft

When looking at the Minecraft Bedrock Edition scripting API I noticed it uses JavaScript and I was wondering if I could use TypeScript instead. When I looked it up online I didn't really find a straight answer if I could (I know TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript by Microsoft and that Minecraft Bedrock Edition is also by Microsoft but I want to be 100% sure I can use TypeScript before I dive in and learn it) which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: TypeScript needs to be translated down to JavaScript anyways. So you **should** be able to just write TypeScript and end up with consumable JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. JavaScript and TypeScript are fundamentally the same syntax-wise though, and since it's just an API it's pretty much the same. So technically no but keep in mind it's mostly sticking to *a.register("e"); a.e(5,2);*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you need to have node.js in order to use typescript.

Here is a link to the docs:[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/minecraft-scripting-samples/minecraft-typescript-starter-project/)

Answer (score -1):

You **can** use `TypeScript` according to this article: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-mod-minecraft-without-java-f076ddaec01c. There is even a written and video tutorial.

Comment: That's not for the official Minecraft scripting API

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thank you for your suggestion. I will keep it in mind in the future.